# What is difference between using a colon (:) when creating a class to use inheritance and the 'using' keyword at the top of the program code?

Tags: c#, inheritance

```
using System.Web.UI;

namespace MyTestCode
{
    public partial class login: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
```

Aren't the above just identical ways to include the methods in the System.Web.UI.Page class? But why is one preferred over the other?

I guess there is something I don't understand about inheritance.

Comment: The `using` directive has *absolutely nothing* to do with inheritance.

Comment: Microsoft Docs.... [Inheritance in C# and .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/inheritance) ... [using directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)

Comment: Using simply allows you to use a namespaces content without using fully qualified names. Like the first comment said, nothing to do with inheritance

Comment: The reason for `System.Web.UI.Page` when you have access to the types in that namespaces is that `Page` may be ambiguous since it's such a simple word (like, for example, if you have a `Page` entity in your EF context and you have a `using` directive for that namespace, too). This makes it unambiguous that you want to inherit from `System.Web.UI.Page` and not something else.

Comment: You really should try to follow your own assumptions and at least cursory test those out - what exactly make you think `using System.Web.UI; public partial class Login{}` makes `Login` derive from the  `System.Web.UI.Page`?

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, I know that the ''using" keyword is not inheritance.  What I am trying to ask is WHY use the inheritance thing (colon) when creating the class?  Why not just do this:       var myObj = new System.Web.UI.Page   and then use methods in the object  "myObj" when needed in the programming code?  What benefit does using the inheritance thing (colon) do for you in the programming code?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Web.UI
```

Doesn't mean your class is now inheriting anything, it's just a way to import namespaces to be used in your class. You can think of namespaces as libraries, each library has useful classes the can help you create things based on your needs.

For example if i want to do some math operations, there is no need for me to create most of those operations from scrtach, all i have to do is importing the System namespase like this:

```
using System;
```

Now since i have the System name space imported, i can use the Math class that lives inside the System namespace:

```
var floor = Math.Floor(Decimal);
```

You still can achive this without using the namespace, but you have to do it like this:

```
var floor = System.Math.Floor(Decimal);
```

Same goes for your example above, you can do it like this:

```
    namespace MyTestCode
{
    public partial class login: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
```

Or you can do this

```
using System.Web.UI;
namespace MyTestCode
{
    public partial class login: Page
    {
```

Comment: `using System;` does not give you access to the `Floor` method without the class name. For that, you need `using static System.Math;`. But `using static` is not what OP is asking about.

Comment: @madreflection thank you! corrected, my example was just for demonstration...

Comment: Also, you said *"You still can achive* [sic] *this without using the namespace"*, but you mean "without the `using` directive" because what you show next is *with* the namespace.